# Graphic driver problem with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 32-bit

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 by upgrading from 11.10 32-bit and I am unable to display anything within any windows open when I load Ubuntu.

My computer has the following video card:
G86 [GeForce 8300 GS]

I'm trying to enable proprietary video drivers from the root shell prompt loaded in recovery mode.  I was wondering how to do this, starting with how I enable a wired internet connection from the root shell prompt.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! What have you tried so far? Could you restate your question? What are you trying to do - installing drivers or setting up an internet connection? Try to ask one question for each issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. To enable your ethernet connection, you should only have to select "Network" at the recovery mode menu. After pressing Enter, your file systems will be checked for errors and mounted in read/write mode. Then the wired network connection will automatically be set up.
2. After this you will be taken back to the recovery mode menu. Select "root" and type `apt-get install linux-headers-generic nvidia-current`. Press ctrl+alt+delete to reboot.

(Someone may edit this answer to provide instructions for jockey-text)